# Google Drive authorization from opencpu

Tags: r, opencpu

I've been trying for a while to use the library `opencpu` to import some Gdrive files (binary files, not Gsheets or Gdocs) using the R library `googledrive`. My code works great locally or deployed as a `Shiny` application but it seems `Opencpu` can't read `.httr-oauth` (or I don't know where to put it in order for Opencpu to be able to read it). Anyway I always get the following error: `"failed to create server"`.

I've tried to save the auth token as a local file and to load it in `opencpu` without success, I've tried to put the `.httr-oauth` file in data folder, in www folder, in inst/www folder and even in R folder, but it doesn't work.

My code is like this (I removed references to actual Gdrive files):

```
Estrai <- function(dataset,start=NULL,end=NULL) {
  library(googledrive)
  library(foreign)
  library(openair)
  drive_auth()
  x<-as_id("https://drive.google.com/open?id=xxxxxxx")
  drive_download(x,overwrite=TRUE)
  x2<-as_id("https://drive.google.com/open?id=xxxxxxx")
  drive_download(x2,overwrite=TRUE)
  spc<-read.dta("xxxxxx.dta")
  spc$date<-as.POSIXct(paste0(spc$year,"-",spc$month,"-",spc$day," ",spc$hh,":00"),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
  bo<-read.dta("xxxx.dta")
  bo$date<-as.POSIXct(paste0(bo$year,"-",bo$month,"-",bo$day," ",bo$hh,":00"),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
  if (dataset=="dr"){
    uscita1=paste0("SPC: da ",min(spc$date)," a ",max(spc$date))
    uscita2=paste0("BO: da ",min(bo$date)," a ",max(bo$date))
    uscita=paste(uscita1,uscita2,sep="\n")
  }
  if (dataset=="spc"){
    uscita=selectByDate(spc,start,end)
  }
  if (dataset=="bo"){
    uscita=selectByDate(bo,start,end)
  }
  return(uscita)
}
```

'''

Any idea?
Thank you.